# Stripe javascript code review

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am getting a error 402 after a customer has enter their card parameters and submits the order. Note: there is no capture, the card parameters are records in the customer's account in Stripe to be captured at a later time. It was working then, not working one day. Not sure if Stripe has changed anything but here is the javascript code, I think it has to do with the status console:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_live_xxxxrTZawxjutHNRrXbJJ9c');

var show_error, stripeResponseHandler;
$("#card_code").on('change',function (event) {
    var $form;
    $form = $(this);
    $('.continue').attr("disabled", true);
    processcard()
    return false;
});
var processcard = function(){
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: $('#card_number').val(),
        cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
        exp_month: $('#expires').val().slice(0,2),
        exp_year: $('#expires').val().slice(2,4)
    },stripeResponseHandler);

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response){
        console.log(status);
        if(status == 200){
            $("#user_card_token").val(response.id);
            $('.continue').removeAttr("disabled");
        }else{
            $('.continue').attr("disabled", true);
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend writing into Stripe on this one! Stripe support can look at your account and get a better sense of what is happening here! https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: Did you use real card info? or test card? `402 - The parameters were valid but the request failed.` Sounds like card info are wrong!